# повторно запускается таймер

Tags: javascript, таймер

добрый день. 
накрутил не очень понимая, но нужно срочно..
Таймер на пол часа должен запускаться при прокрутке до него.
Получилось странное: после запуска таймера если покрутить колесико цифры дергаются как будто таймеров 2.
Подскажите, пож, как поправить. 
Спасибо.

```
$(window).on('scroll', function () {
    var fiveMinutes = 60 * 30,
    display = $('#time');
    var cont4 = $('#seventh').offset().top;

  if ( $(this).scrollTop() > cont4 - 200) {

    startTimer(fiveMinutes, display);
  }
});
```

Comment: А где ограничение повторного запуска?

Comment: искал как это сделать, но что-то по моим поисковым запросам попадается не то.
Не подскажете, как запретить повторный запуск?

Comment: Создаете флаговую переменную, в которую кладете `true`, если таймер уже запущен, и по которой не даете повторно его запустить.

Comment: `var fiveMinutes = 60 * 30` - это странно

Comment: jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {
 $(window).on('scroll', function () {
  var fiveMinutes = 60 * 30,
        display = $('#time');
  var cont4 = $('#seventh').offset().top;
    var flag = false;
   if (( $(this).scrollTop() > cont4 - 200) && (!flag)){    
    startTimer(fiveMinutes, display);
    flag = true;
   }
 });
}); 

что-то я сделал не так, потому что все равно цифры дергаются. помогите пож.

Answer (score 0):

```
jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {
    var flag = false;
    $(window).on('scroll', function () {
        var fiveMinutes = 60 * 30,
        display = $('#time');
        var cont4 = $('#seventh').offset().top;     
      if (( $(document).scrollTop() > cont4 - 540) && (!flag)){     
        startTimer(fiveMinutes, display);
        flag = true;
      }
    });
});
```

не там поставил сточку. Этот код работает. решает проблему. Спасибо.